# is GPRS module has Its own MAC Address

Tags: gprs

I read pdf of **GPRS module** ... But there is no description about Module's (Hardware) **MAC address** ..

Can anyone help me to out this problem, I want to get MAC address (if module has).

Comment: It's probably the IMEI number you're after if you want some sort of unique ID.